# Reset flutter views when leaving flutter module inside native app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I have to include a FlutterViewController as part of my native App. The Engine is created on app start. If the user clicks on an item in a native view the Flutter App opens and loads the data that it receives via some method channels.

Until here it is working. Now the user gets back to the native app and clicks on a different item. Now again the Flutter part is invoked, calls the method channels to get the needed infos to show and shows them.

The problem I'm facing now is, that when the user clicks on the second, third, ... item the flutter part opens and shows for a very short time the data of the old item, which is obviously not so good for the user experience.

My question now. Is there a way in Flutter or in the native part to kinda reset flutter in background, without destroying the flutter engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experiments the solution was to natively react to the state and send a custom `'reset'` through a methodchannel

Comment: Hi @Hons - thanks for responding with your solution. 
Would you, by any chance, be able to share more details on how you are achieving this? Things like - when do you call the custom 'reset'. 

Also, did you notice this behaviour on both iOS & Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can show a loading indicator when loading data. Refer below

```
final Future<String> _calculation = Future<String>.delayed(
  const Duration(seconds: 2),
  () => 'Data Loaded',
);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DefaultTextStyle(
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!,
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    child: FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: _calculation, // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        List<Widget> children;
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          children = <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.check_circle_outline,
              color: Colors.green,
              size: 60,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Result: ${snapshot.data}'),
            )
          ];
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          children = <Widget>[
            const Icon(
              Icons.error_outline,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 60,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
            )
          ];
        } else {
          children = const <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              width: 60,
              height: 60,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
              child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
            )
          ];
        }
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: children,
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```